# Soccer Results: Count wins when 4 or more goals scored by speciied team

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following in excel:

```
        A           B      C     D        E
1     Arsenal       3      v     2    Liverpool
2     Arsenal       4      v     1    Chelsea
3     Liverpool     1      v     1    Spurs
4     Arsenal       3      v     0    Stoke
5     Arsenal       6      v     2    Huddersfield
```

What I would like to do is count how many occasions Arsenal won then game when they scored 4 or more goals. In the example above I would need to return "2" as they beat Chelsea 4-1 and Huddersfield 6-2.

I have tried countifs, sumifs, sumproducts but I am going round in circles.

Any help would be appreciated.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Is column A the home team? In which case presumably you need to also look for instances where Arsenal are the away team and win with 4 or more goals?

Comment: I posted two possible answers, one for each option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Countifs()` is the formula you need. These are the conditions:

```
COLUMN A = ARSENAL
COLUMN B > COLUMN D
COLUMN B > 3
```

Read [the documentation here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) and give it a try once again.

Comment: Didn't realise I could use Column B > Column D.  Thought that would mean an array formula.  But it all worked perfectly :)

Comment: No, you can't use Column B > Column D with COUNTIFS - You may be able to set it up that way, but it won't work as expected, i.e. to compare each value of column B against each one from D, you need SUMPRODUCT or another array formula

Comment: @barryhoudini - I have to admit that you are right (although I do not want to) :D

Comment: @AlanTingey - how did you manage to build up the formula with `Countifs()`?

Comment: If you use a formula like this: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"Arsenal",B1:B5,">"&D1:D5,B1:B5,">3")` then that actually compares all 5 B1:B5 values against D1, then all B1:B5 values against D2 and so on, so that formula returns an "array" of 5 results - the result you see in the cell will depend on whether you use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER or where you put the formula otherwise (e.g. it might show different results in placed in G1 or G2). If you think that works try changing the Chelsea score to 4 (for a 4-4 draw)

Answer (score 1):

If Arsenal can only be in column A then you can use this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="Arsenal")*(B1:B5>D1:D5)*(B1:B5>=4))`

....or if Arsenal could also appear in column E (as away team?) then you can use this version

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="Arsenal")*(B1:B5>D1:D5)*(B1:B5>=4)+(E1:E5="Arsenal")*(D1:D5>B1:B5)*(D1:D5>=4))`